# Why does lean add implicit variables to lemmas from eq?

Tags: formal-verification, lean

The following code has a strange behavior

```
variable (toto : Type)
check eq.symm  --output: eq.symm : ?a toto = ?b toto → ?b toto = ?a toto
```

I would expect check to not take into account the irrelevant implicit variable toto when showing me the type of eq.symm.
Is this really intended?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I don't expect the lemma showing symmetry of equality to speak about the variable toto, as it applies to any type irrelevant of whether it depends on toto. In Coq for example:

    Variable toto : Type.
    Check eq_sym.

returns:
    eq_sym : forall (A : Type) (x y : A), x = y -> y = x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from [github issues here](https://github.com/leanprover/lean/issues/1067).

This is actually a bug referenced [here](https://github.com/leanprover/lean/issues/1068) which can be worked around by doing either

```
print eq.symm -- theorem eq.symm : ∀ {A : Type} {a b : A}, a = b → b = a :=
          -- λ A a, eq.rec (eq.refl a)

check @eq.symm -- eq.symm : ∀ {A} {a b}, a = b → b = a
```